# sklearn linear_kernel to make cosine_similarities - Memory Error

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to find the cosine similarity using the sklearn TfidfVectorizer due the large size of the data I am keep getting the memory error

```py
tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 3),max_df=1.0, min_df=0, stop_words='english')
tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(ds['description'])

> cosine_similarities = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix) <-- Memory Error
```

Please help me to resolve the error. Thanks a lot

Comment: do you know what a memory error is?

Answer (score 0):

If you get an unexpected `MemoryError` and you think you should have plenty of RAM available, it might be because you are using a 32-bit python installation.

The easy solution, if you have a 64-bit operating system, is to switch to a 64-bit installation of python.

The issue is that 32-bit python only has access to ~4GB of RAM. This can shrink even further if your operating system is 32-bit, because of the operating system overhead.

more here: https://superuser.com/questions/372881/is-there-a-technical-reason-why-32-bit-windows-is-limited-to-4gb-of-ram